# JSF table component with high demo value

Tags: java, jsf, demo

As part of an ongoing quest for a nice web demo in a couple of weeks we now have a list of customers where we are considering presenting an HTML table with a row of core details for each, and then allowing the user to ask for additional details.

This could be in a mouse over, an opening up the table inserting a panel of details, or opening a popup window.  Right now I am looking for a JSF table component optimized for ooh-aah-value doing one or more of the above.  Until now I've stayed with the core JSF components, and the h:dataTable is functional but rather un-oohaahish.

I'd appreciate suggestions.  Links to videopresentations are appreciated even more :)

(Note:  I'm using the latest Mojarra, so JSF 2.0 is fine)

---

EDIT:  To wrap things up:  We went with OpenFaces 3.0EA2 for the web demo with very nice visual results, but found that the documentation for getting up and running with the full bells and whistles is simply not there and there is too much pixie dust.  We ended adjusting the existing demo (which is extremely impressive) to deal with our data instead.

Comment: @leppie, this is not a Java question, no need to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, oohaahishness requires a good shot of CSS. This is indeed not included in the standard JSF implementation. So, you'd like to look for a component library which includes CSS skins/themes. They usually have a component showcase at their homepage. There are several:

1. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) - [Datatable component demo](http://www.primefaces.org/labs/ui/datatableHome.jsf) - [Theme gallery](http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html)
2. [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org) - [Datatable component demo](http://openfaces.org/demo/datatable/DataTable_general.jsf)
3. [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) - [Datatable component demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf)
4. [IceFaces](http://www.icefaces.org) - [Component showcase, check *Table*](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface) (URL is not bookmarkable)

Comment: @org.life.java RichFaces does not have full control library for JSF2. 
I wouldn't invest time into it right now.

Comment: @Thor: The ordering is already a little hint to my (current) recommendation when taking JSF 2.0 into account :) I personally find their Theme Gallery very good and smart as well (in the showcase, there's a "Change Theme" dropdown at left top, give it a try). The average CSS designer is familiar with [jQuery's Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). That's a big plus.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Anderse - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402952/richfaces-vs-primefaces. I didn't try OpenFaces, and IceFaces icefaces cannot work with primefaces or RichFaces, and is not as quick as the others.

Comment: I had a look, and liked the OpenFaces demo best (most oohaahish).

Comment: If it's only the oohaahishness counts, then OpenFaces indeed wins. But there's after all more into the story than oohaah :) One has to develop and maintain the whole final thing after all.

Comment: Right now it is the oohahhness that counts.  Our software has an expected lifetime in decades, and I am very much aware that maintainability is crucial.  For the real thing we will reevaluate carefully.

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck with demo, Thorbjorn! :)

Answer (score 1):

Supporting BalusC's answer, I will add that PrimeFaces [lab table demo](http://www.primefaces.org/labs/ui/datatableHome.jsf) even have new features.

In order to use the jar, [download the lab showcase demo](http://repository.prime.com.tr/org/primefaces/prime-showcase/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/prime-showcase-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war) and open the war from your IDE (e.g. eclipse). You will see how to use it.