# Make editable rows in Datatable

Tags: jsf

I have list of rows displayed on the screen. These rows are iterated using the JSF datatable component. Now my requirement is to edit any particular row which user clicked.

Is there any way to make the fields editable while user clicking the row. Then user will fill the details and save it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating editable data tables is very easy with jsf. [Here is a good tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) on this. But "making it editable when user clicks on it" is not supported out of the box. And this is where JSF shines, you just need to find for a JSF component (open source or commercial) compatible with your JSF (1.x or 2.x) version and start using it.

My first suggestion for you is to check and see if PrimeFaces provides this kind of component. [Here is the component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf) you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is PrimeFaces good. I want to know if it is better than RichFaces and IceFaces. Please let me know.

Comment: I have worked with rich faces, trinidad etc but not icefaces. PrimeFaces is the winner.

Comment: What inspire you to suggest the prime faces. Can you please put down few points.

Comment: Very good out of the box component and theme support, fast, frequent releases, good support in the forum, i believe 1st one to implement jsf 2, check here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402952/richfaces-vs-primefaces