# using RichFaces and PrimeFaces in the same application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces

Can RichFaces (either 3.x or 4.x) and PrimeFaces (either 3.5 or 4.0) be used in the same JSF 2.x application? Will they coexist nicely?

My goal is migrating from RichFaces 3.x to PrimeFaces. I would like to start by using PrimeFaces for a new submodule of my web application, and eventually migrate everything.

It would be fairly easy to set up a simple hello-world sized project and try it out; I am asking here because I wish to know if there are some problems when doing this on real-life sized projects.

Comment: In theory there's no problem to do that. Both of them are independent libraries which access jsf functionalities in their own way. You should be able to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, your comment would make an useful answer.

Comment: Haven't tested it by myself, so could not provide you a decent answer. In theory it's possible to achieve. Practically, you can search for issues some people had ([here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/230784) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117808/is-that-possible-to-combine-primefaces-and-richfaces-in-one-web-application)). File uploading seems to be a field where you could have problems.

Comment: I have tried to use both of them but if you try to use component does not behave properly

Comment: For the person that voted this question as a duplicate, I must say that the possible dup question dates from 2011 year, and after almost 3 years all JSF, RichFaces and Primefaces have evolved and have newer versions, but basically the answer is the same: yes, you can use both but may have compatibility issues, so it would be better choosing one of them according to your needs/requirements.